# What are the best practice, and standard tools for blinding algorithms?

Tags: standards, blind-signature

I'm developing an app that uses blind signatures. I'm having a hard time finding tools, and best practices for blinding. There is no PKCS. And everywhere I go, I find caveats of different blind signature schemes.

I've read mixed things about RSA blinding, and looked at this RSA blinding algorithm. But it doesn't seem to have any users. https://github.com/cryptoballot/rsablind

I also found this ECC example which uses the bitcoin curve. But it isn't idiomatic go code, and has no users.
https://github.com/mndrix/btcutil/blob/master/examples/blind/blind.go

In my app, Alice blinds her public key, and gets it signed by a signing authority, the unblinds it. She later signs documents with her private key. Observers check Alice's document signature with her public key, and they check that Alice's public key is signed by the signing authority. The signing authority should not be able to associate blind messages it has signed to unblinded signatures.

Comment: The lack of standards is caused by the lack of need / applications. However there should be a few academic papers on the subject (no reference right now).

Comment: U-Prove might be a nice introduction into blind signing, for a signature scheme produced from a proof of equality of two logarithms. A book is available on credentica.com

Comment: Maybe you can look into ISO/IEC 18370